# JQuery Polling and Response Processing

Tags: javascript, jquery

not really sure how to put the question, but here is my problem.

I have AJAX polling request like this

```
function poll(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/?Request=PollingData",
        success: function(data, textStatus, request){
            var event = data.split("}");
        }
    });
}

setInterval(poll, 500);
```

I might get multiple events in one poll like {event=event1&data=aaa}{event=event2&data=bbb}.

My objective is to get the events, and at some places I want to put a code that will loop for forever to process the events. I want to move whatever events I received in the poll to somewhere so that I can loop each event before I can pass it to a specific eventHandler.

This is because when I do the poll every half of a second, the process in the eventHandler might not finished yet. So if I received a new events, I want to push all the new events to process with the existing events. Lets say I am looping event1 and event2, and it takes 2 seconds (which is more than half of a second), and then new events come during the next poll, I want to append the event so that now I can loop event1 event2 event3 event4. If you don't quite understand the requirement, let me know.

I am having a problem on how to do and what should I put because I used JQuery just for the basic stuff and does not has very deep knowledge in this. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This would typically involve multiple thread(one for ajax, one for processing), something javascript does not allow you to do. However, I've never experienced any problems with doing the processing in the success callback. If you have, please try to explain the problem in a more concrete way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just make sure the polling only occurs after the event processing is finished, you could just set the poll event to not occur until after the event processing is done, rather than with an interval, like this:

```
function poll(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/?Request=PollingData",
        success: function(data, textStatus, request){
            var event = data.split("}");
            /* .. processing code */
            setTimeout(poll, 500);
        }
    });
}
```